# How to copy files from folder tree dropping all the folders with Robocopy?

Tags: command-line, command-prompt, robocopy

I have the following folder structure:

FolderA
--Folder1
--Folder2
--Folder3
...
--Folder99

Folders 1 through 99 have files in them.

All I want to do is to copy ALL THE FILES into ONE FOLDER, basically do a FolderA copy, and wipe out Folders 1-99 keeping all the files.

I'd like to do it with Robocopy from cmd.exe if possible (Windows Server 2008)

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming question.

Comment: you guys can move it to SU or SF, i don't want to delete it and waste a useful answer

Comment: batch programming is still programming

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Why use `robocopy`? It's a good tool for a specific task but this is not the one.

You can simply use what `cmd` already gives you:

```
for /r %f in (*) do @copy "%f" target
```

This will essentially "flatten" your directory hierarchy. `for /r` will walk a directory tree recursively, looking for file names matching the given pattern. You can also specify the directory to start in:

```
for /r FolderA %f in (*) do @copy "%f" target
```

Within the loop it's just a simply copy of the file into a specified folder.

Comment: There are 2 solutions [here](http://mlichtenberg.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/command-line-fun-how-to-flatten-a-folder-hierarchy/) if you have files that don't have unique names.

Comment: Which option can be used when there are duplicates with the same name?

Comment: @Martin: See `help copy`. It's `/y`.

Answer (score 3):

Robocopy is a great tool... when you have a job it can handle. Why not use xcopy?

If you have two drives you can just use xcopy:

```
XCOPY  C:\*.*  D:\NewFolder\   /S
```

Or use XXCOPY for one drive:

```
XXCOPY C:\*.*  C:\NewFolder\   /S /CCY
```

[XXCOPY](http://www.xxcopy.com/xxcopy16.htm)

Comment: user /SGF attribute to copy into one folder

Comment: xcopy duplicates the directory structure. I think the question is about flattening the directory structure.

Answer (score 3):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path source -Recurse -File | Move-Item -Destination dest
```