# Fastest approach to copy millions of JPGs to destination with Robocopy and Powershell?

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I want to copy all JPGs within a directory (including subfolders) to a target destination (flat hierarchy).
My Powershell Script seems super slow :(

Any ideas how to make the fastest approach? Is robocopy a faster solution?
It seems that Robocopy always also creates the folder of the JPG. But I want it flat like
C:\destination\image1.jpg
C:\destination\image2.jpg
C:\destination\image3.jpg

Is it possible that only images are copied that arent already in the target folder?

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "R:\XXX\*" -Include *.jpg -Recurse | Copy-Item -Destination $targetpath -verbose
```

Comment: If you are going for speed I think a test for exist will slow you down. Is the script much longer then what you wrote here? 
What kind of location is r drive and the target?

Comment: Replace `-Include` by `-Filter` which should be faster as it uses filter at the filesystem API level, instead of PoSh filter which is applied later.

Comment: Check this out. It uses Windows batch commands (instead of PowerShell) along with ROBOCOPY. [ROBOCOPY - Copy folders content to a single folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8691073/2441)