# Batch file "for" command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Need to be able to "schedule" a command line action using windows scheduler.

This is my command:

```
for /r C:\Users\bob\Downloads\Done\ %f in (*) do @move "%f" C:\Users\bob\Downloads\Done\
```

It flattens all files into the main folder.

The "for" command does not work as in a scheduler but is working in cmd.exe

I need a batch file or other code so that I can use the scheduler.

I read these, but I'm just not that cool:
[How to copy files from folder tree dropping all the folders with Robocopy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502170/how-to-copy-files-from-folder-tree-dropping-all-the-folders-with-robocopy)

[How does "FOR" work in cmd batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817280/how-does-for-work-in-cmd-batch-file)

Comment: **for** is built into cmd.exe, so you can just use `cmd` as the command and `/c for /r ...` as the parameters. Alternatively put the line into a .cmd (or .bat) file (i.e., create a script) and schedule the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take your above code and save it in a `.bat` file.  The only change you need to make, is that percents (%) need to be doubled-up when run inside a batch file.

```
for /r C:\Users\bob\Downloads\Done\ %%f in (*) do (
    @move "%%f" C:\Users\bob\Downloads\Done\
)
```