# How to run SQL scripts from command prompt directly

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlcmd

I want to run 20 SQL scripts from a folder on a database in SQL Server.

My SQL Server is called `SQL_SERVER_1`, my database is called `SQL_DATABASE_1`.

I have 20 SQL files (01 - file, 02 - file, 03 - file, etc) in a folder `c:\Users\Me\Desktop\New Folder`.

I'm unable to get the syntax correct for this.

On a separate note: is there any way I run all the files inside the folder consecutively one after the other, without having to write the command for every file?

Comment: Look at the FOR command on the command line to run them all in a single command: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24316254/2557263

Comment: what error messages are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can:

Locate SQLCMD.EXE, depends on version of SQL server

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE" -U <UserName> -P <Password> -S (local)\SQLExpress -i "c:\Users\Me\Desktop\New Folder\01 - file.sql"
```

To run it for all files check ForFiles.

```
forfiles -M *.sql -C "cmd /c <your path to SQLCMD>SQLCMD.EXE <your connection parameters> @Path "
```